# Populating a WPF ListBox based on a ComboBox Selection

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, xaml

I am trying to populate a WPF ListBox with data from a SQL Stored Procedure based on a ComboBox Selection. I've gotten the ComboBox to work like its supposed to, but I can't get the ListBox to display any data. My naming might be a little weird, but think of it as: the ComboBox gets all Recipes from SQL and the ListBox needs to display a list of Ingredients and their Amounts based on the users selection from that ComboBox. The API and Stored Procedures(...GetAll() for the ComboBox and GetByRationId() for the ListBox...) work, as I can retrieve the correct data using Swagger in the API and I can Populate the ComboBox and the RationId TextBlock in the UI, but I can't get the ListBox to show any data. I am still new to programming and I'm following tutorials etc. and I can't seem to find anything that speaks to my case specifically. I'm guessing I'm missing something. I've added the aforementioned TextBlock just to display the RationId, which is what needs to be used to get the correct data from SQL, as a test, just to make sure that the Id was getting through...and it is.

Here's the Xaml...

```
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="50" Orientation="Vertical">
        <ComboBox x:Name="FeedGroup" MinWidth="300" MinHeight="50"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFeedGroup}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FeedGroupName}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
        
        <TextBlock x:Name="SelectedFeedGroup_RationId" Height="81"/>

        <ListBox x:Name="FeedGroupRation" MinHeight="200" Padding="20" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedFeedGroupRation}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CommodityName}" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CommodityPercentage}" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox> 
    </StackPanel>
```

Here is the ViewModel Class...

```
public class FeedGroupPageViewModel : Screen
{

    IFeedGroupEndPoint _feedGroupEndPoint;
    IFeedGroupRationEndPoint _feedGroupRationEndPoint;
    IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly StatusInfoViewModel _status;
    private readonly IWindowManager _window;


    public FeedGroupPageViewModel(IFeedGroupEndPoint feedGroupEndPoint,
            IFeedGroupRationEndPoint feedGroupRationEndpoint,
            IConfigHelper configHelper,
            IMapper mapper,
            StatusInfoViewModel status,
            IWindowManager window)
    {
        _feedGroupEndPoint = feedGroupEndPoint;
        _feedGroupRationEndPoint = feedGroupRationEndpoint;
        _configHelper = configHelper;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _status = status;
        _window = window;
    }

    protected override async void OnViewLoaded(object view)
    {
        base.OnViewLoaded(view);
        try
        {
            await LoadFeedGroup();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    private async Task LoadFeedGroup()
    {
        var FeedGroupList = await _feedGroupEndPoint.GetAll();
        var feedGroup = _mapper.Map<List<FeedGroupDisplayModel>>(FeedGroupList);
        FeedGroup = new BindableCollection<FeedGroupDisplayModel>(feedGroup);
    }

    private BindableCollection<FeedGroupDisplayModel> _feedGroup;
    public BindableCollection<FeedGroupDisplayModel> FeedGroup
    {
        get { return _feedGroup; }
        set
        {
            _feedGroup = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => FeedGroup);
        }
    }

    private FeedGroupDisplayModel _selectedFeedGroup;
    public FeedGroupDisplayModel SelectedFeedGroup
    {
        get { return _selectedFeedGroup; }
        set
        {
            _selectedFeedGroup = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedFeedGroup);
        }
    }



    private BindableCollection<FeedGroupRationModel> _feedGroupRation;
    public BindableCollection<FeedGroupRationModel> FeedGroupRation
    {
        get { return _feedGroupRation; }

        set
        {
            _feedGroupRation = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => FeedGroupRation);
        }
    }

    private BindableCollection<FeedGroupRationModel> _selectedFeedGroupRation;
    public BindableCollection<FeedGroupRationModel> SelectedFeedGroupRation
    {
        get { return _selectedFeedGroupRation; }
        set
        {
            _selectedFeedGroupRation = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedFeedGroupRation);
        }
    }
}
```

And here are the Model Classes

```
public class FeedGroupDisplayModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string FeedGroupName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
    public int RationId { get; set; }



    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void CallPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}


public class FeedGroupRationModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public int RationId { get; set; }
    public string RationName { get; set; }
    public int CommodityId { get; set; }
    public string CommodityName { get; set; }
    public int CommodityPercentage { get; set; }



    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void CallPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And Here are My Endpoint Classes

```
public class FeedGroupEndPoint : IFeedGroupEndPoint
{
    private IAPIHelper _apiHelper;

    public FeedGroupEndPoint(IAPIHelper apiHelper)
    {
        _apiHelper = apiHelper;
    }

    public async Task<List<FeedGroupModel>> GetAll()
    {
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await _apiHelper.ApiClient.GetAsync("/api/FeedGroup"))
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<FeedGroupModel>>();
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public class FeedGroupRationEndPoint : IFeedGroupRationEndPoint
{
    private IAPIHelper _apiHelper;

    public FeedGroupRationEndPoint(IAPIHelper apiHelper)
    {
        _apiHelper = apiHelper;
    }
    public async Task<List<FeedGroupRationModel>> GetRationById()
    {
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await _apiHelper.ApiClient.GetAsync("/api/FeedGroup"))
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<FeedGroupRationModel>>();
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can add more info if needed. I've been working on this for quite awhile now and I'm just out of ideas. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Two things. 1. I think the `SelectedFeedGroupRation` property of the view model should be of the type `FeedGroupRationModel`. 2. How are you loading the `FeedGroupRation` collection after the `SelectedFeedGroup` changes? That's not apparent to me from the code you've provided.

Comment: @StevenB: Where and how do you set the `FeedGroupRation` property?

Comment: 1) What is the source of ComboBox.ItemsSource = ...?
2) If the INotifyPropertyChanged interface is declared in your class, then all properties must be either "Read Only" or notified of their changed through this interface.
3) BindableCollection, as I understand it, implements INotifyCollectionChanged. If so, then it is better to make the property "Read Only". And if necessary, completely change the collection, you need to clear it and fill it with new elements.

Comment: @EldHasp: I've added an `ItemSource` to the xaml code of my question. I bound it to `SelectedFeedGroupRation`...not sure if that is right or not though. Not sure what your meaning in #3. I am using TextBlocks in an attempt to just get this up and going but I will want to be able to change the returned values of the ListBox (in something like a TextBox) and then push the updated values back to the server.

Comment: If I understand your explanation correctly.
You select the desired group in ComboBox.
You have this group in the SelectedFeedGroup property.
The easiest way is to add in the set method the SelectedFeedGroupf properties  when the value changes, calling the method that modifies the collection in the SelectedFeedGroupRation property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Michal Davis comment stated I was missing a method for loading the ration, so I added LoadFeedGroupRation()...

```
    private async Task LoadFeedGroupRation()
    {
        var _feedGroupRation = await _feedGroupRationEndPoint.GetRation();
        var feedGroupRation = _mapper.Map<List<FeedGroupRationDisplayModel>> 
        (_feedGroupPenList);
        FeedGroupRationList = new BindableCollection<FeedGroupRationDisplayModel> 
        (feedGroupRation);
    }
```

Also based on @EldHasp's comment I updated the SelectedFeedGroup setter...

```
public FeedGroupDisplayModel SelectedFeedGroup
{
    get { return _selectedFeedGroup; }
    set
    {
        _selectedFeedGroup = value;
        var FeedGroupRation = LoadFeedGroup
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedFeedGroup);
    }
}
```

I Don't know if this was the best way but I worked for my case.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to set the `FeedGroupRation` that the `ListBox` binds to somewhere.

I guess you want to fetch the items and set the property when the `SelectedFeedGroup` property is set. You could then hook up an event handler to the `PropertyChanged` event or override the `NotifyOfPropertyChange` method. Something like this:

```
public override async void NotifyOfPropertyChange([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    base.NotifyOfPropertyChange(propertyName);
    if (propertyName == nameof(FeedGroup))
    {
        //get the items...
        var results = await ...;
        //set the source property
        FeedGroupRation = results;
    }

}
```

Comment: I've added my `LoadFeedGroupRation()` Method to the ViewModel Class in my question. I've tried adding your code as you have it, awaiting said `LoadFeedGroupRation()` method but I get the error: "Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable". Any Ideas?

Comment: What's the return type of your `LoadFeedGroupRation` method?

Comment: The `LoadFeedGroupRation()` method needs to return a list of `FeedGroupRationModel`.

Comment: @StevenB: What? And how is this related to your question...?